# In Lucene 4 what is the distinction between AtomicReader and CompositeReader

Tags: java, lucene

Trying to convert some Lucene 3 code to Lucene 4,

I want to use termEnums.docs(ir.getLiveDocs()) to only return docs that have not been deleted for a particular term. However getLiveDocs() is only available for AtomicReaders, and although I just have a single index it is file based and uses DirectoryReader (which is a subclass of CompositeReader).

So I guess I could use SlowCompositeReaderWrapper but the name deters me from this, but what I don't understand is that isnt almost everyone using indexes based on the filesystem, isn't almost everyone using CompositeReaders ?

Yet the documentation seems to be implying we should be using AtomicReaders but I dont understand how I could possibly do this with a file based index, maybe if the file based index only had a single segment, but aren't segments created by Lucene as it requires them and not usually closely controlled by the end user application.

Comment: May I ask you whether the answer was useful? You might want to accept it if it was.

Comment: javanna yes it was useful, although I was hoping for a few more replies as Im not sure to write my code, this change still seems to have made lucene unneccessarily complex

Comment: I see your point! I agree it's quite tricky, on the other hand it's something that people need to be aware of when using lucene. That's one of the main reasons why elasticsearch is usually a better fit, even for a local small index; you can actually concentrate on your data without knowing all those details about lucene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question. That's probably the most common one that pops up when migrating from lucene 3 to lucene 4.
Have a look at [this article](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/02/is-your-indexreader-atomic-major.html) first, which explains the reason behind the refactoring.

Basically everything is per segment in lucene, but some of the lucene 3 APIs didn't reflect that. Some of the methods exposed by the `IndexReader` in lucene 3 were just merging a lot of information from all the segments and doing slow things, which is the reason behind the naming of the `SlowCompositeReaderWrapper`. The idea is to get the information that you need from every segment and merge it yourself. An `AtomicReader` gives you access to a single segment, while the `CompositeReader` is a view of the whole index, which doesn't expose all the methods that used to be available through the `IndexReader` though.

Comment: Thx, Ive got the concept but I dont see the advantage in me handling multiple segments myself rather than lucene handkling it for me, I dont see that I could do it in a more performant way.

Comment: Tha advantage is that if you do it like that it's faster, but probablyless handy in terms of code. Faster because you only read the information that you need instead of haveing lucene to do too many on-the-fly merge that you don't need.

Comment: I still dont get it, if I have an index that runs over multiple segements how can I write my code that needs to read stuff from multiple segments so it is faster than the lucene 3 code.

Comment: From the `IndexReader`, so called top-level reader, you have access to all its subreaders through the `leaves` method. Just iterate over them and read the information that you need, putting it in a common date structure.